# Comparing two Linked lists in Java

Tags: java

I am solving a problem on how to compare two nodes given their heads. 
I can not figure out what is missing in my code.I am solving this problem on a programming site I did not understand the input so I am not able to understand why my program is not doing what I have expected.

Input Format 
You have to complete the int CompareLists(Node* headA, Node* headB) method which takes two arguments - the heads of the two linked lists to compare. You should NOT read any input from stdin/console.

```
 int CompareLists(Node headA, Node headB) {

        if(headA==null || headB==null){
            return 0;
        }

         else if(headA == null && headB == null) {
        return 1;
        }

        while(headA!=null &&headB!=null){
            if(headA.data==headB.data){
                headA=headA.next;
                headB=headB.next;
            }
            else{
                return 0;
            }
        }
         return 1;

    }
```

Input (stdin)

4

4

1 2 3 4

4

1 2 3 4

3

1 2 3

4

1 2 3 4

1

12

1

13

2

4 15

2

15 4

**My output**
1
1
0
0

**Expected output**
1
0
0
0

Comment: Nor can we.  Largely because you haven't told us what the problem is.  Or what a `Node` is.

Comment: If you want to return `1` when both lists are `null`, you need to reverse the order of the `if` tests. As it is, the second `if` test will never be reached when it would evaluate to `true`.

Comment: `it is not passing the Testcases` is not a useful edit.  You need to show us a sample input, your expected output, why you think you expect this output (beyond simply "the test case says so"), and the actual output.

Comment: You might want to explain the input format so we don't have to guess. (Actually, all that is irrelevant, the point you really want to make is that the method fails when one list is {1, 2, 3} and the other is {1, 2, 3, 4}.)

Comment: can you explain the input format

Comment: Surely the input format will be explained clearly in the problem statement?

Comment: Input Format 
You have to complete the int CompareLists(Node* headA, Node* headB) method which takes two arguments - the heads of the two linked lists to compare. You should NOT read any input from stdin/console

Comment: @TedHopp changing that isn't working.

Comment: @JoeC can you explain me the input please.

Comment: What is it, _specifically_, about the input that you don't understand?  (And please quote the relevant section of the problem description when answering that question.)

Comment: specifically i did not understand the input , what is the first list? what is the second list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two (possibly three) problems with your code.

First, the order of the first two `if` tests needs to be reversed:

```
if (headA == null && headB == null) {
    return 1;
}

if (headA==null || headB==null){
    return 0;
}
```

In your current code, the first test will succeed whenever the second test would have succeeded, so you will always return `0` when either (or both) lists are `null`.

Second, your `while` loop exits whenever either list becomes `null`, but you should only return `1` when both lists are `null`. (That is, the two lists are equal only if they are the same length and all elements have equal data values.) Change the last line to:

```
return headA == null && headB == null;
```

You might have another problem, depending on the data type of the `data` field in `Node`. If it is a primitive type (`int`, `double`, etc.), your code is fine; if it is a reference type (e.g., `String`), you probably should be using `.equals()` instead of `==` to test equality.

```
if(headA.data.equals(headB.data)){ ... }
```

P.S. Is there any reason to return an `int` value instead of a `boolean` truth value?

Comment: The prototype of the function is already given and I just have to implement it .

Comment: @Karthik - Gotcha.

Comment: can you tell me what I should change , I dint understand the second part of your answer

Comment: The short version of the second part is to simply replace the `return 1;` that appears at the end of your method with `return headA == null && headB == null;`, for the reason explained in the answer.

Comment: headA=null && headB=null will be boolean

Comment: @Karthik - My bad. Change it to `return headA == null && headB == null ? 1 : 0;`

Answer (score 0):

try `if(headA.data.equals(headB.data)`

Also be sure to implement and override the `Node` `equals()` method

https://www.sitepoint.com/implement-javas-equals-method-correctly/

Comment: What would be the use of an `equals()` method for `Node` objects in OP's problem?